# Tag a user in a profile post with Graph API

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an app for iOS and trying to implement the "tag" people feature found in the official Facebook app. When you tag people, it will automatically display "blablabla With username".

The API requires me to tag a place also. Why is this? I just want to say that "I am with username". Not specify the place. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, from the docs:

> tags  Comma-separated list of Facebook IDs of people tagged in this Post. For example: 1207059,701732. This field is returned as the with_tags field when the Post is read. NOTE: You cannot specify this field without also specifying a place.

Answer (score 0):

You can issue a direct POST to the Graph API endpoint `me/posts`, which allows you to optionally tag people and/or add location. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts for more info.